# Enviar en tiempo real el valor de una variable socketio

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io, websocket

Estoy intentado mostrar en tiempo real el valor de una variable, esta variable se puede cambiar mediante una llamada a la API, el problema es que una vez que se muestra el resultado no se vuelve a actualizar, habría alguna forma de que cada vez que se actualize la variable se haga el emit?

```
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");

const mysql = require("mysql");
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "mobileusers"
});

con.connect(err => {
  if (err) throw err;
});

  var MI_VARIABLE = "TEXTO";

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  const router = require("./router");
  const app = express();
  const server = http.createServer(app);
  const io = socketio(server);

  app.post("/cambiar", (req, res) => {
    const { nom } = req.query;
    MI_VARIABLE = nom;
    res.send("Se ha cambiado el valor de la variable");
  });
  io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("estadoVariable", MI_VARIABLE);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("El usuario se ha desconectado");
    });
  });

  app.use(router);

  server.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${PORT}`)
  );
```

**EDIT:**

**Frontend**

De frontend estoy usando React Native, como mencione antes solo carga el primer estado de la variable(del backend) y luego no actualiza más, aunque cambie el valor de la variable mediante la api :/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://192.168.1.126:5000");

export default function PanelTrabajador() {
  const [miTexto, setMiTexto] = useState("texto inicial");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("estadoVariable", data => {
      setMiTexto(data);
    });
  }, [miTexto]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{miTexto}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: puedes poner el código que tienes en el frontend?

Comment: añadido en el edit 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que necesitas es hacer un `emit` a ese evento y eso lo puedes hacer haciendo uso del método [emit](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args)

Adaptado un poco tu código el ejemplo funcional seria así.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

/**
 * @description Metodo que envia a TODOS los usuarios que estan escuchando a esa referencia
 * @param {string} reference 
 * @param {any} message 
 */
function emit(reference, message) {
    io.emit(reference, message);
}

//TODO: Cambiar a post.
app.get("/cambiar", (req, res) => {
  const { nom } = req.query;
  // Enviamos a la ref. estadoVariable el valor que nos han pasado por los parametros
  emit("estadoVariable", nom)
  res.send("Se ha cambiado el valor de la variable");
});


server.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Server start in: http://localhost:5000');
});
```

Y el código para `frontend` por si quieres probarlo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");


export default () => {
    const [miTexto, setMiTexto] = useState("texto inicial");

    useEffect(() => {
      socket.on("estadoVariable", data => {
        setMiTexto(data);
      });
    }, [miTexto]);

    return(
    <h2>{miTexto}</h2>
    )
}
```

> No es react-native, pero el código es el mismo.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar.